# LD_PRELOAD in rlwrap?

Tags: linux, bash, ld-preload, rlwrap

When I do something in my script like

```
rlwrap -f words.txt LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so command "$@"
```

I always get something like

```
rlwrap: error: cannot execute LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so no such file or directory
```

Even though that file totally exists and removing rlwrap would work just fine.

How do I put LD_PRELOAD in rlwrap? basically I want to make mylib.so apply to my '`command`' only.

I did try putting `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so` in from of rlwrap, it runs, but LD_PRELOAD didn't apply to `command` as I wished.

Comment: Looks to me like `rlwrap` is taking `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so` as the command. Have you tried `LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so rlwrap -f words.txt command "$@" `

Comment: @Mort yes, but that didn;t work. Then LD_PRELOAD was not passed into command

Comment: Hmmm. On my system, `LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libc.so.6  rlwrap sh -c 'echo $LD_PRELOAD'` prints `/lib/libc.so.6`. If it does the same on your system, `rlwrap` _is_ passing `LD_PRELOAD` into the environment of  the rlwrapped command

Comment: @HansLub Yes, but the linker links `mylib.so` against `rlwrap` which is not desired

Comment: @hek2mgl: That depends. If `mylib.so` defines just a few symbols that aren't used by `rlwrap` (which is a common case) it is quite OK to do it this way.

Comment: If that's *really* the case then yes. But that's an edge case. Wrapping the command in a shell like I showed looks cleaner imo

Comment: As I said, that depends. But yes, your solution will _always_ work, and mine _may_  go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the command in a shell:

```
rlwrap -f words.txt bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=mylib.so command "$@"' - "$@"
```

Comment: hm, what does the last part: - "$@" do?

Comment: Passing the arguments of the current shell to the sub shell